# Rails: singular resource update path issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing, form-for

I'm struggling to get the correct url to give to form_for for update action to work on singular ressources.

My routes.rb is as follow:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|fr/ do
  namespace :quickwizard, :module => 'quick_wizard' do
    resource :business, controller: 'business'
  end
end
```

which give the following routes:

```
     quickwizard_business POST   (/:locale)/quickwizard/business(.:format)          quick_wizard/business#create {:locale=>/en|fr/}
 new_quickwizard_business GET    (/:locale)/quickwizard/business/new(.:format)      quick_wizard/business#new {:locale=>/en|fr/}
edit_quickwizard_business GET    (/:locale)/quickwizard/business/edit(.:format)     quick_wizard/business#edit {:locale=>/en|fr/}
                          GET    (/:locale)/quickwizard/business(.:format)          quick_wizard/business#show {:locale=>/en|fr/}
                          PUT    (/:locale)/quickwizard/business(.:format)          quick_wizard/business#update {:locale=>/en|fr/}
                          DELETE (/:locale)/quickwizard/business(.:format)          quick_wizard/business#destroy {:locale=>/en|fr/}
```

and in the view:

```
= simple_form_for @business, url: quickwizard_business_path(@business), validate: true do |f|
```

generates an incorrect url for update (but works for create):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/15/quickwizard/business" ...
```

if I put the correct route manually instead, it works for update:

```
= simple_form_for @business, url:"/quickwizard/business", html: { method: 'put' }, validate: true do |f|
```

So my question is: what is the proper way to do this so the url I put works both for create AND update actions ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides in the locale, not in the singular resource. Try to generate the url with

```
quickwizard_business_path(@business, locale: nil)
```

Comment: Doesn't fix it. I updated the routes.rb to include the scope (didn't think of posting it). Given that I specified the possible options for the locale, how come the business id could be mistaken for a locale ?